# Angular9 sanitizer: Sanitizer return null

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular9

I try to import and use Sanitizer as follow but then I get null when try to console.log sanitizer

```
import { Component, OnInit, Sanitizer, SecurityContext } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-summarise-written-text',
  templateUrl: './summarise-written-text.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./summarise-written-text.component.css']
})

export class SummariseWrittenTextComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(
    private sanitizer: Sanitizer,
  ) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    console.log(this.sanitizer.sanitize(SecurityContext.HTML, '<div>some text here\n but error</div>'));
  }
```

[image: my code]

[image: when I console.log]

Comment: Perhaps you really want to use `import { DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser';`?

Comment: Thanks Richards, my code works well with DomSanitizer. But I am just wondering why it does not work with Sanitizer on my code. It works with Angular on Stackblitz. I just update everything to Angular 10 but still no hope.

Comment: Can someone tell me reason behind for working with DomSanitizer and not working (gives null value) for Sanitizer ?